# Conditional Logic on CF7 dropdown options

Tags: customization, plugin-contact-form-7

I need to create a form with two dropdowns ("Translate from" and "Translate to"), many options (Languages) inside on those dropdowns.

If someone selects any language other than "English" the second dropdown should only have the option "English".

How can I accomplish this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for an option that we can hide the specific option inside the dropdown.

But I was able to accomplish this using Conditional Fields plugin.

**But if anyone knows a way to do this within dropdown options please answer. Thanks!**

```
[select translate-from "Translate From" "French" "English" "Hindi" "Spanish"]

[group group-584][select translate-to1 "Translate To" "French" "Hindi" "Spanish"]
[/group]

[group group-585][select translate-to2 "Translate To" "English"]
[/group]

[select select-service "Select Service" "Service 01" "Service 02"]

[number number-words min:0 placeholder "Number of Words"]

[submit "Get Started"]
```

**Conditional Logic**

```
show [group-585] if [translate-from] not equals "English"
show [group-584] if [translate-from] equals "English"
```